# How to raise all values to the power of 2, but keep their original sign

Tags: python

How do I raise all values for the vector v = [4,7,-2,9,3,-6,-4,1]to the power of 2, but keep their original sign ?

Comment: Um... squaring a negative number makes it positive. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Could you add the expected output?

Comment: yes the expected output will be v = [16,39,-4,81,9,-36,-16,1]

Comment: What have you tried? 
Do you know how to do this for a single number? (i.e., `-x -> -x^2)?
Do you know how to square a vector of numbers, without keeping the sign bit?

Comment: Cocomac it is a an excercise about modifying vectors

Answer (score 4):

I like @Sören's method better, but if you prefer not to have to `import math` for some reason, this will work.

```py
>>> v = [4,7,-2,9,3,-6,-4,1]
>>> result = [x*abs(x) for x in v]
>>> print(result)
[16, 49, -4, 81, 9, -36, -16, 1]
```

We do `x * abs(x)` and to keep the sign. If the original number is positive, both `x` and `abs(x)` will be positive, yielding a positive answer. If the original is negative, `x` will retain the original sign, meaning we get a negative.

I use a list comprehension, and then wrap it in `int(...)` to make it an int again (from a float).

Comment: That won't work for `x == 0`, and it's simpler and likely faster to use a conditional expression to select `1` or `-1` as appropriate for the value of `x`.

Comment: You can just to `x * abs(x)`

Comment: @EdwardPeters Thanks, I've updated it to that. `x == 0` wasn't in the list of cases it needs to support

Comment: @cocomac I like your's, because it doesn't overflow.

Comment: the "int" part make no sense, the abs of an int is an int

Comment: @Copperfield you are fully right. In an older revision I was using division and abs to find the sign. This method is better, but I forgot to remove the int.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> from math import copysign
>>> v = [4,7,-2,9,3,-6,-4,1]
>>> [int(copysign(x*x,x)) for x in v]
[16, 49, -4, 81, 9, -36, -16, 1]
```

The [copysign](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.copysign) function basically does what you want: Return the first argument, but with the sign of the second. Except that copysign always returns a float, so if you want ints, you cast them back. (Beware of overflow!)